# installing MongoDB on ubuntu wsl2 systemd issue systemd as init system (PID 1)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, systemd

**installing MongoDB on ubuntu wsl2**

---

I tried to install MongoDB on WSL( ubuntu 20), after using [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database) but there is something wrong!
I don't know what the heck is: `systemd :"System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1)"` and how should I resolve that...
I'm totally beginner in Linux experience.
I've searched for this problem and apparently, people using DOCKTER in wsl had such a problem but I can't figure out how should I do in my case.
thanks

The whole error:

```sh
Setting up mongodb-org-server (4.4.4) ...
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Cant operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--configure):
installed mongodb-org-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up mongodb-org-shell (4.4.4) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-mongos (4.4.4) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-database-tools-extra (4.4.4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-org:
  mongodb-org depends on mongodb-org-server; however:
  Package mongodb-org-server is not configured yet.
    
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up mongodb-org-tools (4.4.4) ...
  No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
  mongodb-org-server
  mongodb-org
```

Comment: AFAIK, wsl does not need systemd. I tried to install mongodb in wsl on my own, but I couldn't and I found that for some reasons it was not possible. Alternatively, I installed the mongodb server in windows and used it in wsl container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of searches and trial and error, I found the only thing it apparently needs to do is: right after the MongoDB installation ("[In this Lik](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)"), we should set "systemctl" to enable!
And then it needs to reboot your system.

```
sudo systemctl enable MongoDB
```

Comment: Why is the answer selected? WSL/WSL2 does not come with systemd. Therefore running **systemctl** will just generate an error: **System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1).**

Comment: @John Hanley is correct.