# I got an illegal instruction when installing mongoDB when trying to check the version

Tags: database, mongodb, windows, ubuntu

Hey so I tried installing mongoDB and I can't get it to install correctly. I am installing it on wsl on a windows computer and I keep getting illegal instruction when I try to check the version and it won't let me finish installing it. Here are the instructions I used to install MongoDB (version 5.0) on WSL (Ubuntu 20.04):

- Open your WSL terminal (ie. Ubuntu) and go to your home directory: `cd ~`
- Update your Ubuntu packages: `sudo apt update`
- Import the public key used by the MongoDB package management system: `wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -`
- Create a list file for MongoDB: `echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list`
- Reload local package database: `sudo apt-get update`
- Install MongoDB packages: `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`
- Confirm installation and get the version number: `mongod --version`
- Make a directory to store data: `mkdir -p ~/data/db`
- Run a Mongo instance: `sudo mongod --dbpath ~/data/db`
- Check to see that your MongoDB instance is running with: `ps -e | grep 'mongod'`
- To exit the MongoDB Shell, use the shortcut keys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: Does it shows any errors while installing the mongo packages? Can you post the output of `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`?

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mongodb-org is already the newest version (5.0.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 162 not upgraded.

Comment: i also get this error when trying to start it:

System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Comment: Have a look at this answer, see if it works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66411178/14774959